# mysqli execution failing when using bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a mysql query that I am using to log into the database but for some reason it is returning -1 even though i put in the right values and the same query executes without the bind_param

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$user_array = array('username' => $username,'password' => $password );  
$queryname = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

function auth($queryname,$user_array) {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($queryname);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $user, $pass);  
        $user=$user_array['username'];
        $pass=$user_array['password'];
        $stmt->execute();       
        return $stmt->affected_rows;        
    }
```

Any suggestions as to how i can debug this ?

Comment: i have done that now

Comment: From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) ~ *"-1 indicates that the query has returned an error"*. Also, a `SELECT` query is **never** going to result in `affected_rows`

Comment: @Phil could there be anything wrong in my bind_param i am using an md5 hashed text, which is stored as varchar

Comment: Run this before you create your connection `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` and watch the errors come rolling in ;)

Comment: Thanks, though my solution was answered my someone else, i now know of a better way of debugging mysqli

Comment: It's invaluable. They should have it on the `mysqli_connect` manual page. The best thing is, you can now use exception handling. So, was there an actual error in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$stmt->affected_rows` returns the total number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php):

> This function only works with queries which update a table. In order to get the number of rows from a SELECT query, use [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) instead.

Change `return $stmt->affected_rows;` to:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
return $count;
```

Comment: @Bazinga777 also you must close $stmt: see modified code